# Does work equal to the amount of energy transported by potential difference?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, potential, work

I Googled up some things in thermodynamics, but I'm still confused about a few basic one.

If I mix warm and cold water in a tank the mixture will have the potential and kinetic energy of atoms, but that energy won't be useful to do work. If warm up the top of the water in a tank, but the bottom part not, as it won't mix immediately, there will be a potential difference caused by the difference of temperatures. (The warm and cold water have the same temperature as the ones I mixed. Only now they are separated.) And this makes energy transfer possible. And work is a form of energy transport. Based on how I understand this:

1. Work is energy, but only the part that being transfered during the process.
2. The potential difference of temperature is a difference in energy. So this means that temperature is energy.
3. The cold water has less energy. The potential difference is the amount of energy, the warm water has more compared to the cold one. And based on point one, the work can be done is also equal to this.

What I don't understand right?

Comment: Can you quote the exact wording of the material (the google results) you are asking about?

Comment: There will initially be heat transfer between the top and bottom of the tank due to the temperature difference but no work because there that would require a pressure difference.

Comment: The story of the tank and water is what my teacher said in school. What I tried to google up we're definitions. I read a bunch of quietons on Quora about difference between work and energy, about temperature etc. I don't know what questions I visited exactly, because it was yesterday. If something doesn't make sense in this question, please tell me. There isn't a certain article I don't understand. Just if these statements are true or not?

Comment: But if we have only pressure difference and no temperature difference the work still be possible. So this work independent from heat. It comes from the potential difference of pressure. So only by temperature difference doing work won't be possible? If this is the case is work still a form of energy? Only not the one that contains heat?

Comment: @CsavarCsavar Both heat and work are means of energy transfer. Heat is energy transfer due solely to a temperature difference. Work is energy transfer due to net force times displacement.

Comment: @CsavarCsavar Regarding the title of your post,  I do work pushing a box between two points on a horizontal floor yet there is no potential difference between the two points.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks linked to your numbered statements.

1. Work transfers energy by means of a force moving through a distance in the same direction as the force. Example: a gas at low pressure in one half of a cylinder is separated from a gas at higher pressure in the other half by means of a piston, which is held in place. It is then released, allowing the higher pressure gas to do work on the lower pressure gas and to transfer energy (equal to the work) to it.
2. Energy – called *heat* in this case – will spontaneously flow from a body at a higher temperature to a body at a lower temperature. To this extent there is an analogy with positive charge flowing from a place at a higher potential to one at a lower potential.
3. Usually if we increase a body's internal energy (either by doing work on it or by letting heat flow into it) its temperature will rise, but the rise in temperature isn't necessarily proportional to the increase in internal energy. [As an extreme example, if we feed energy into ice at 0°C  it will melt but, while melting, its temperature won't change, though its internal energy increases.] Temperature is certainly not energy!

On the other hand, for a gas at not too high a density the temperature is nearly proportional to the *mean* kinetic energy of the molecules. This suggests why energy flows from a hot gas to a cold gas when the molecules collide with a conducting wall separating them. The close correlation between temperature and mean molecular kinetic energy doesn't follow through exactly to liquids and solids.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hope it helped. I've added another paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

In physics '[work](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/energy/Lesson-1/Calculating-the-Amount-of-Work-Done-by-Forces)' is said to be done when force applied on an object results in it's displacement (with positive component of displacement in direction of applied force). Less precisely it's formal way of conveying effect of force on something. If you push against a wall you are actually not doing any work since the effect of your push on wall is nothing. When a ball is thrown up the gravity is against the direction of motion hence the work done by gravity is negative! (Negative means gravity is not contributing productively, it's resisting the motion).

Apart from mechanics, thermodynamics has another interesting perspective. In winters you rub your hands to get warmth, your are converting work into energy! But since energy is eternal ,(can't be created can't be destroyed) this means work is nothing but the energy in disguise.

> Work is energy, but only the part that being transfered during the process.

Not exactly, because work has no independent existence. You can't say a system has some quantity of work. Work is energy in transit, it's not part of energy in transit. It's similar to heat in this case (this leads you to [first law of thermodynamics,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics) Q = U + W).

> Heat and work are both energy in transit—neither is stored as such in a system. However, both can change the internal energy, U, of a system. Internal energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of a system's atoms and molecules.([source)](https://www.texasgateway.org/resource/122-first-law-thermodynamics-thermal-energy-and-work)

> So this means that temperature is energy.

No,not at all! Temperature is measure of energy. Your weight is some pounds this doesn't mean you are same as pounds. Temperature is abstract thing, a castle in air, which exist only in your head. Thermometer is an amazing piece of Engineering, you should understand it's working first to know real meaning of temperature.([this book](https://elearn.daffodilvarsity.edu.bd/pluginfile.php/987150/mod_label/intro/fundamentals-of-physics-textbook.pdf) has amazing explanation on this matter)

> The cold water has less energy. The potential difference is the amount of energy, the warm water has more compared to the cold one. And based on point one, the work can be done is also equal to this.

It depends, from mechanics point of view you can't say anything about energy content based on temperature. Take for example, cold water is on Mount Everest and hot water on ground then obviously cold water has more potential energy!

In thermodynamics meaning of terms are very precise, the proper term to use will be Internal Energy, cold water has more internal energy than hot water, due to mixing the systems will exchange heat till equilibrium is attained (which is not so simple hence engineers have to study heat transfer). Yes work done is equal to heat transfered (and we thank Joules for telling us [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat)).

Happy learning!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.